# Why LaTeX is free?

Tags: discussion

Recently that question appears and I am not sure why when many people use and develop LaTeX, it is still free and we can download the program without any problem. That is so much good as strange.

I know also Linux is free and so on, but it seems different with LaTeX, which is available even for paid Operative Systems (OS) as Windows or Apple.

So: Why latex is free?

Comment: If someone gives you money for free, you better not to ask why.

Comment: LaTeX is hardly unique in this regard. And Apple's OS is based on free software.